# Why is AssemblyQualifiedName of anonymous type not always the same?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I was trying to find an anonymous type from a collection of assemblies by AssemblyQualifiedName, but though the anonymous type is present in the scanned assembly it's not found. GetTypes() seems to return types with other AssemblyQualifiedNames.

Why are the AssemblyQualifiedNames different, and what can I do to find the correct type in the given assemblies?

```
    [Fact]
    public void AnonTypes()
    {
        var entity = new { SomeString = "Asger" };
        var type = entity.GetType();
        var assemblyQualifiedName = type.AssemblyQualifiedName;

        var types = type.Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.AssemblyQualifiedName == assemblyQualifiedName)
            .ToList();

        types.Count.ShouldBe(1);
    }
```

Please note that Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName) finds the type, but I can not use this method as I not always have the AssemblyQualifiedName, but some other qualifier to search for.

Also note that same thing happens if entity is a ValueTuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that code like

```cs
var x = new { SomeString = "" };
```

creates a Type like

```
public class AnonymousType0<T> 
{
    public T SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

So `x.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` returns a name of the type containing the generic type infos.
To get it to work you need to call `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` to get rid of the generic type infos.

For example the type `List<int>` would have AssemblyQualifiedName like ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1[[System.Int32, ...]], ... ``` but in `assembly.GetTypes()` you would find ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1, ... ```.

Comment: Thanks, but why does the types returned from assembly.GetTypes() not return the same AssemblyQualifiedName (with the generic type info)? I believe that if I use GetGenericTypeDefinition() I will not find the closed generic type that I need - or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: `assembly.GetTypes()` returns a list of all defined types. In case of generic types like e.g. `List<T>` it would contain the _type_ `List<T>` but not the derived type `List<int>`.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I was under the delusion that the closed form of anonymous types were also defined in the assembly. Now I see they are clearly not, and that it would make no sense :)

Comment: Forgot to mark as answer, sorry, done now :)